# Why does this statement run before the if statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && isset($_POST['repeat-pass'])){

  $fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
  $password_post = $_POST['pass'];
  $confirmpassword_post = $_POST['repeat-pass'];
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, hash('sha3-512' , "$password_post"));
    $confirmpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, hash('sha3-512' , "$confirmpassword_post"));

    if($password != $confirmpassword){
        header("Location: index.php?failed=2");
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    header("Location: index.php?failed=1");
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
         header("Location: index.php?failed=3");
    }

    $ip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

   mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `users` (`full_name`, `email`, `username`, `password`, `date`, `ip`) VALUES ('$fullname', '$email', '$username', '$password', '$date', '$ip')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    header("Location: index.php?success=1"); 
}
```

My problem is, that when the both passwords are unequal, and the fi statement should send the user to index.php?failed=2.
It does not work it will run the mysqli_query(Insert) first and redirect the user to index.php?success=1.
But why when the if statment is before the other, why does it runs after the success redirect?

Comment: You should `exit;` right after `header` Location: it does not stop itself, it shouldn't. So code evaluates to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sending the location header won't work, as PHP will continue executing the script.

You need to add a `die();` after each `header` call to ensure that PHP stops evaluating the rest of the code.

Comment: oh wow, know i have learned again something. Thank you so much